# Why are servo potentiometers in the 5k range?

Tags: potentiometer, servo

I've [looked](https://www.rcgroups.com/forums/showthread.php?1039247-What-is-the-typical-resistance-range-of-a-Servo-POT) [around](http://www.rccrawler.com/forum/electronics/522911-how-many-ohm-potentiometer-servo.html) a bit and it seems that servo potentiometers are in the ~5kOhm range. Why 5k?

Ultimately it's just a linear voltage divider, so:

1. *Aside from idle power consumption*, does the value matter?
2. What might be the problem to use higher or lower values, of lets say, [200-Ohm or 100-kOhm](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/54/3590-776468.pdf) pot?

Comment: 200 ohms across a 10V supply (common in industrial gear) gets you a pot dissipating 1/2W - much more than most pots are rated for, and a notable source of heat.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As with all nominal value resistors, too low means high power consumption, too high means higher Johnson resistor noise, more voltage from shot noise in amplifiers, and will upset other components which have high leakage or bias currents, especially in a damp environment. The 'sweet spot' for this particular component is however very large, and anything from 1k to well over 100k would probably work OK.

It does seem that the industry has settled on a *de facto* standard value. This is great, until you assume they are all like that, design assuming it, and then get one that isn't.

Comment: can you extrapolate on "too high means noisy" ? Is that because the current is too low to reduce noise-induced voltage fluctuations on the tap pin providing the output voltage for measuring (in this case) servo position?

Comment: One other reason could be that the cheap 8-bit MCUs like PIC16F, ATmegaxx8 have ADCs with input impedance specifications at 10kΩ max.

Comment: 5-10k is a very popular range for all kinds of resistors and potentiometers, there's nothing special about servo potentiometers that they'd have a different range. It's easy to work with and relatively easy to produce, so there's no reason *not* to produce a default in that range.

Comment: @KJ7LNW Look up Johnson-Nyquist noise. It's a phenomenon that occurs in resistors, and it's proportional to resistance.

Comment: Pots have one more reason to keep their usable value reasonably low - the mechanical wear of the resistive material. Too thin layer and you start to get bad contact after fewer rotations.